# SVG path not parsing correctly: svgpathtools, Inkscape

Tags: python, xml, svg, gimp, inkscape

I'm tyring to get an array of points on the a particular path (it's a teapot). I made the path and exported it using the "Inkscape" and "Gimp" software.

I'm trying to parse the svg file (essentially an XML file) using the library `svgpathtools` and espetially the `parse_path` function. The normal behavior of `parse_path` is to -well parse- the "d-string" of the SVG and create a `Path` object.

However, I get an error:

```
File (...)\parser.py", line 112, in parse_path
  control1 = float(elements.pop()) + float(elements.pop()) * 1j
  ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'
```

Here are the first few lines of the SVG file:

```
  <path id="Sélection"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 1381.00,143.00
           C 1382.71,149.01 1394.44,175.21 1397.93,180.00
             1400.62,183.69 1402.89,185.74 1405.83,189.00
             1405.83,189.00 1429.69,216.00 1429.69,216.00
             [...]
             1403.00,127.29 1381.00,143.00 1381.00,143.00 Z
           M 2296.00,978.00
           C 2296.00,978.00 2293.17,942.00 2293.17,942.00
             2293.17,942.00 2288.72,891.00 2288.72,891.00
             2288.72,891.00 2276.88,838.00 2276.88,838.00
             [...]
             2315.00,967.85 2296.00,978.00 2296.00,978.00 Z
           M 326.00,1040.00" />
```

The file is 250 lines long.
This is the problematic piece of my code:

`path = svgpathtools.parse_path(filepath)`

And here the full, unredacted error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vikto\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\vikto\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\vikto\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\vikto\Desktop\Best_Dossier_ever\Python\TeapotProj\TeapotProject.py", line 34, in <module>
    path = svgpathtools.parse_path(fpath)
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\svgpathtools\parser.py", line 112, in parse_path
    control1 = float(elements.pop()) + float(elements.pop()) * 1j
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'
```

I'm afraid the error might be due to incorrect formating since the CubicBezier function has parameters `start, control1, control2, end` all in complex `a + bj` format. It seems here that there are fewer parameters !? Would it be Inkscape/Gimp that doesnt format it well (I doubt that) ? Or something else?

Rope will be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: If the file is 250 lines long, create a [mcve] by removing everything that doesn't contribute to the problem and post that code instead, and post it in the form that actually breaks. A path `d` attribute doesn't need to be 1000 characters long: just remove the parts that don't trigger this problem until you basically have a form `<svg ...><path d="m 0 0 c 10 10 20 20 30 30"/></svg>` that still triggers the error you're seeing. Also, the error you get says `could not convert string to float: 's'`, so: show your code. What are you doing around line 112?

Comment: `@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's a great point! Actually the error doesn't give me where in the file the error occurs, and line 112 corresponds to the library's souce code file... I was also quite uncertain as to what I should put in the question....

Comment: it's python: you generallly get a huge stack trace that goes through everything from the library to your own code, so another thing is "post the actual error" rather than trying to redact it. As for your edited SVG: edit it further. If things break on a `C` then having 20 of them makes literally no difference: just have one, and verify things still break with that single M + C instruction. Does it not break? Cool, then you now know what _isn't_ a problem and you can look deeper.

Comment: The svg file is just has the svg head tag, and the path tag consisting of all the CubicBezier "calls" with the appropriate points

Comment: Seems like while getting rid of all but one M+C instruction the same ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'``` is given, I might need to parse only the ```path``` tag since the "s" here might come from the ```</svg>``` closing tag

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer!
Here the problem was that I was parsing the whole SVG file and not only the "d-string" part.
To get the actual string:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
mydoc = minidom.parse(file_path)
path_tag = mydoc.getElementsByTagName("path")
d_string = path_tag[0].attributes['d'].value
Path_elements = svgpathtools.parse_path(d_string)
```

Here, Path_elements is a list of Path objects defined by the CubicBezier curves. 
As to the "fewer" points, actually the end of one Bezier curve is the start of the other, hence no need for 5 parameters but only 4 and a start "M" instruction point!

Shoutout to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for the help !